# Prepend to vector scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Newbie to scala, im finding the symbolic notation for dealing with collections confusing. To append an item to a list or vector i can use:

```
List(1, 2, 3) :+ 4
```

which i understand to be the infix form of this method

```
List(1, 2, 3).:+(4)
```

if i want to prepend to a list i can use

```
List(1, 2, 3).+:(4)
```

However the infix form gives me a compile error

```
List(1,2,3) +: 4
Error:(121, 16) value +: is not a member of Int
Vector(1,2,4) +: 4
              ^
```

Can someone enlighten me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, methods which end in a colon `:` and are used in infix notation are *right associative*, meaning the method is on the element present on the right hand side. You need:

```
4 +: List(1,2,3)
```

When using `List[T]` with the dot notation this doesn't happen because that is an explicit call on list. When using infix notation, the compiler does additional syntax desugaring. This:

```
List(1,2,3) +: 4
```

Is turned into

```
4.+:(List(1,2,3))
```

But doesn't find a `+:` on `Int`, so it complains.

Comment: thanks can recommend some resources on the basics of modifying the collection api and how to interpret the overloaded operators, the scala docs on the subject are pretty sparse

Comment: @LukeDeFeo I'd start with https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html